# TensorFlow Lite Error: "(RESHAPE) failed to prepare" when running converted RepNet model in TFLite in Flutter

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I'm trying to run a converted [RepNet](https://sites.google.com/view/repnet) model in TFLite on mobile (iOS and Android) using Flutter, and the [`tf_lite_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter) package.

I have successfully converted the model to TFLite by adapting the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/google-research/blob/master/repnet/repnet_colab.ipynb) provided by the authors. The notebook I used can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/Automated-Exercise-Repetition-Counting/RepNet-TFLite-Converter/blob/1b7e9d72fa1295906cd948f382389d1782261123/Convert_repnet_to_tflite.ipynb), along with the [converted model](https://github.com/Automated-Exercise-Repetition-Counting/rep_net_flutter/blob/abe12d98b6d74928d4a07a6f2347a6cebe095015/assets/repnet2.5.tflite).

To make sure everything was working before attempting to run on an edge device, I checked everything with the Python TFLite API ([this notebook](https://github.com/Automated-Exercise-Repetition-Counting/RepNet/blob/eacb917abb9bdd4e7b1be833ee4928417afacad8/repnet_lite.ipynb)). Everything indeed worked well - the output for the TFLite model matches the output of the Google colab provided by the authors.

I created a [Flutter project](https://github.com/Automated-Exercise-Repetition-Counting/rep_net_flutter) to get the model running on mobile. I've tried passing in the default input and output, resulting from calls to `interpreter.getInputTensors()` and `interpreter.getOutputTensors()` respectively. When [using this project to try to run the model](https://github.com/Automated-Exercise-Repetition-Counting/rep_net_flutter/blob/abe12d98b6d74928d4a07a6f2347a6cebe095015/lib/main.dart), I encounter the following error:

```
E/tflite  (26540): tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:69 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (1 != 0)
E/tflite  (26540): Node number 1 (RESHAPE) failed to prepare.
```

I'm admittedly pretty new to Tensorflow and Tensorflow Lite, so my debugging ability is somewhat limited. It does seem strange to me that the expected output shape is 0. Considering it is working with the Python API, I'm not sure why it isn't working on-device. The only thing I might suspect it could be is the batch_size not being configured properly. Using the `shape_signature` field, as in `interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['shape_signature']`, I can see that the batch size is dynamic (value -1).

The model was converted using `Tensorflow==2.5` in Python, and is being run using the standard `TFLite 2.5` binaries (no `GPUDelegate`).

Any suggestions for fixing this error would be appreciated!